# How to get Nth Largest value with List.Max power query

Tags: powerquery

I have the below were I want to return the 2nd highest value from this list the list.max function works but when I try to sort it to return the 2nd it returns an error, is there any way to return nth largest number in power query?

```
=List.Sort(List.Max({[#"Charge1"],[#"Charge2"],[#"Charge3"],[#"Charge4"],[#"Charge5"],[#"Charge6"],[#"Charge7"],[#"Charge8"],[#"Charge9"],[#"Charge10"],Order.Descending){1})
```

Comment: Use List.MaxN for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `List.Max` in your formula only returns a single value and should be removed.  Either of the following should work:

```
List.Sort(YourList,Order.Descending){1}

List.MaxN(YourList,2){1}
```